# To avoid Web.config file changes again and again

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, visual-studio-2015, web-config, publishing

When I need to publish my Asp.net MVC app to the `Azure Cloud`,these are the steps which I follow. I'm using `VS 2015` as my GUI.

Step 1 : Change the `Web.Config` file's connection string to the production

Step 2 : I don't need to change the build mode to `Release`.I keep that as 'Debug'.

Step 3 : Then publish the app using below mentioned configuration.

[image]

**Q 1 :** Hence I give the connection string on the above configuration,Do I need to change it on `Web.config` file also ?

**Q 2 :** When I use the Data migration (`PM> Update-Database`),I need to change the `web.config` file to appear production's connection string.That means I need to change it again and again on every data migration. Which is really annoying.Is there any better way to do this ? Thanks.

Comment: If you are using an azure website you can store the connection string in the sites settings http://blog.davidebbo.com/2012/09/managing-database-connections-in-azure.html

Comment: @KenTucker Yes,that thing is for the answer of my Q1. But what about the Q2's use case ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the new ASP .NET Core, you'll have the option of using Application Secrets by enabling user secrets during development. On Azure, you can create environment variables for your Web App.

- https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/app-secrets.html

For older versions of ASP .NET, you can use the configSource attribute to keep your connection strings out of web.config. You would use this in conjunction with transformation files for Debug and Prod.

I wrote a blog post about it a while back:

- http://wakeupandcode.com/all-your-database-are-belong-to-us/

Hope that helps, for current and future projects!